# PHP Memcached extension OOP instantiation

Tags: oop, memcached

Background:

I have installed the PHP Memcached extension on my live server.
Despite various efforts, I can't seem to install Memcached within my XAMPP development box, so I am relying on the following code to only instantiate Memcached only on the Live server:

My **connect** file which is included in every page:

```
// MySQL connection here

// Memcached
if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != 'test.mytestserver') {
    $memcache = new Memcached();
    $memcache->addServer('localhost', 11211);
}
```

At the moment I am instantiating each method, and I can't help thinking that that there is a better way to acheive my objective and wonder if anyone has any ideas?

My **class** file:

```
class instrument_info {


    // Mysqli connection
    function __construct($link) {
        $this->link = $link;    
    }

function execute_query($query, $server) {

    $memcache = new Memcached();
    $memcache->addServer('localhost', 11211);

    $result = mysqli_query($this->link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    if($server == 'live') 
    $memcache->set($key, $row, 86400);

 } // Close function


function check_something() {

    $memcache = new Memcached();
    $memcache->addServer('localhost', 11211);

    $query = "SELECT something from somewhere";

    if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != 'test.mytestserver') { // Live server

        $key = md5($query);
        $get_result = $memcache->get($key);

        if($get_result) {    
            $row = $memcache->get($key);    
        } else { 
            $this->execute_query($query, 'live');           
        }

    } else { // Test Server
        $this->execute_query($query, 'prod');
    }

} // Close function

} // Close Class
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you read up on interface-based programming and dependency injection. Here's some example code that might give you an idea about how you should go about it.

```
interface CacheInterface {
  function set($name, $val, $ttl);
  function get($name);
}

class MemCacheImpl implements CacheInterface {
  /* todo: implement interface */
}

class OtherCacheImpl implements CacheInterface {
 /* todo: implement interface */
}

class InstrumentInfo {
  private $cache;
  private $link;

  function __construct($link, $cache) {
    $this->link = $link;
    $this->cache = $cache;
  }

  function someFunc() {
    $content = $this->cache->get('some-id');
    if( !$content )  {
      // collect content somehow
      $this->cache->set('some-id', $content, 3600);
    }
    return $content
  }
}

define('IS_PRODUCTION_ENV', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'www.my-real-website.com');

if( IS_PRODUCTION_ENV ) {
  $cache = new MemCacheImpl();
} else {
  $cache = new OtherCacheImpl();
}

$instrumentInfo = new InstrumentInfo($link, $cache);
```

BTW. You actually have the same problem when it comes to mysqli_query, your'e making your code dependent on a Mysql database and the mysqli extension. All calls to mysqli_query should also be moved out to its own class, representing the database layer.

Comment: Thanks for the code, and the 'push' in the right direction.  I understand the need for this OOP approach and once I get my head around it, I will start coding in this manner.